# directX11 render an animated .gif

Tags: directx-11

I'm wanting to render an animated gif with directX11, using DirectXTex & WICTextureLoader.
I have my thing already rendering png, jpg etc
so I guess it's just a case of passing the correct "frame" but I'm not sure on the procedure, I'm very new to learning code.
code with assumptions

```
auto image = std::make_unique<ScratchImage>();
HRESULT hr = LoadFromWICFile( L"MULTIFRAME.TIF",
                 WIC_FLAGS_ALL_FRAMES, &info, *image );
if ( FAILED(hr) )
    // deal with error

//in testing I get S_OK with this function


// Assuming here I need to do something with this, but not sure what

            ID3D11ShaderResourceView* imgtextureView = nullptr;
            hr = DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromMemory(

// then like other images I pass it to my function that does the rest of the rendering
bitblt(d3dDev, imgtextureView, ARGB(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

Like I said I'm learning so just hints would be welcome

Comment: It's easier with Direct2D (which is a layer above Direct3D11), a sample is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-sample-animated-gif

Comment: Thanks, It doesn't look easier, I'm a beginner.
It might be more work, but I'd more comfortable understanding how to with the thing I have working now.
Even if I'm counting FPS and selecting the next image from the array manually, I'd make quicker progress than trying to figure out a whole other thing.

Answer (score 1):

Code for converting animated GIFs using WIC into texture frames is implemented in the `texassemble` tool for offline use which creates a 2D array texture stored as a DDS file. You can adapt [the code](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/main/Texassemble/AnimatedGif.cpp) for runtime use if you want.

Comment: Thanks, the man the legend himself. Thanks for all your work on the dx stuff. So in runtime once I have populated std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DirectX::ScratchImage>>
in general terms how do I proceed from there?

Comment: After you have the individual frames reconstructed, you can use standard Direct3D operations to load the texture. You can also look at the code in [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/main/DirectXTex/DirectXTexD3D11.cpp) for doing it.